# Why my debian is claiming a broken dep?

Tags: debian

> Context: carefully step-by-step upgrading a Debian 11 to Debian 12

I cannot end my apt-get upgrade becase of this

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  init-system-helpers
```

Additional infos:

```
# dpkg -C
```

Is returning no broken deps

```
root@debian:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-mark showhold
php5-gd
```

I have only this packages marked as hold. And I cannot avoid this, I need `php5-gd`.

When trying

```
apt-get install init-system-helpers
```

I got

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-gd : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

But I already have `libpng12-0 1.2.50-2+deb8u3`

```
root@debian:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get install  libpng12-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libpng12-0 is already the newest version (1.2.50-2+deb8u3).
libpng12-0 set to manually installed.
```

Actually, `php5-gd` is marked as hold, to avoid break a lot of legacy websites on this system.

What should I do?

- I can still rollback to pre-upgrade snapshot
- But I'd like to go on upgrading to debian 12

Comment: Use containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Debian 12, `init-system-helpers` depends on `usrmerge` or `usr-is-merged` (to [enforce the `/usr` merge](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#a-merged-usr-is-now-required)). `usrmerge` conflicts with versions of `libpng12-0` older than 1.2.54-6, and because that package is no longer available from the repositories, `apt` ends up in an impossible solution — it needs to keep `php5-gd`, which requires `libpng12-0`, but it also needs to upgrade `init-system-helpers`, which conflicts with the version of `libpng12-0` you have.

To fix this, install [`libpng12-0` 1.2.54-6 from snapshots](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/libpng/1.2.54-6/#libpng12-0_1.2.54-6).

This will just be a reprieve however; the PHP 5 packages are long-gone, and you should plan on migrating away from them sooner rather than later.

Comment: 1. Thanks. 2: how can I install from snapshot? and also 3: how did you find these info? My system never 'exaplained me' that the source of conflict was `usrmerge`

Comment: If `php5-gd` requires `libpng12-0 >= 1.2.13-4` and `usrmerge` requires `libpng12-0 >=1.2.54-4`, why debian cannot simply install the v1.2.54-4 by itself?

Comment: 2. Download the appropriate package for your architecture from the link I gave, and run `sudo dpkg -i ...` to install it. 3. I knew that `usrmerge` is required for Debian 12, and that `init-system-helpers` depends on it; I also knew that `usrmerge` conflicts with a number of old packages, and that `libpng12-0` is an obsolete package, so all I had to do was check whether `usrmerge` conflicts with that specific package. 4. `apt` can’t upgrade to 1.2.54-6 on its own because none of your configured repositories provide it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All worked, wget + dpkg -i + apt-get full-upgrade